# Dymola working directory is an UNC-path (VM)

Tags: windows, dymola, parallels

Having issues with my Dymola setup. I'm trying a simulation in a VM right now because I have a Mac and I need to wait for my requested PC to be approved. Anyhow... I'm trying to verify the VC compiler VS/Visual Compiler 2019 and I think its finding the right cl.exe but it won't write the `dymosim.c` file in the current directory. It complains about the working directory being a UNC-path but to be honest I'm not that familiar with setups on Windows so I can't tell if its a Windows issue or a Parallels (VM) issue.

Dymola is in `C:\Program Files\Dymola 2021` or at least that's what File Explorer and Command Prompt is seeing it as which doesn't seem like a UNC-path to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't where Dymola is located, but your current/working directory. Type `cd` in Dymola to see what it is.

If the current directory is `\\somecomputer\something\...` it's an UNC-path.

Note that Dymola might try work around this when actually compiling (but not when verifying), but it's still best to correct it.